# MacMini no longer recognizes blank DVD-R's

Tags: mac, dvd

About a month ago my Mac mini stopped recognizing blank DVD-R's.
It recognizes burnt and commercial DVDs, also blank and burnt CD-R's and regular CD's.

I don't think it is a drive problem because i have a built in superdrive and and an external Lacie firewire DVD burner. both do not recognize blank DVD-R's, but does all the others.

I also use toast 10 and have tried re-loading that but no change.
I am guessing it is an OS problem, probably from a security update.
Because I don't make a lot of software / hardware changes.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I had to take matters into my own hands.
I went out and picked up yet another DVD burner. This time a LaCie USB.
Plugged it in. popped in a blank DVD-R and toast opened and Burned the DVD.

So the ANSWER IS: Yes, I had two (2) DVD burners crap out, some what simultaneously.
I guess I should be happy it was not an OS problem Apple was not confessing to.

Still suprized that it is only blank DVD-R's that are not recognized.
I guess they are the first to drop off.

Hope this helps someone else.